# Strange behaviour of open project window in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I've some strange behaviour when trying to open project in netbeans 7.3.1. The names of files/folders aren't fully displayed... You can see in attached image:

[image]

does anyone know what's happening? I need to use that particular version, so moving to the newest isn't possible in that case.

Comment: i had a problem like that.but it was because of my vga problem.

Comment: add -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true to netbeans.conf It may work..

Comment: It's not helping, what's more when I add that line netbeans isn't starting... I've seen in netbeans.conf that most of the options has "-J" prefix but when I add your line with this prefix it brakes the netbeans look...